# A strange result when using reduce with prallelstream in Java

Tags: java

The result of the following code is wrong and random.

```
List<String> list = Stream.of("a", "b").parallel().map(e -> List.of(e + "1", e + "2"))
                .reduce(new ArrayList<>(),
                        (r, l) -> {
                            log.info("accumulator r:{}, l:{}", r, l);
                            r.addAll(l);
                            return r;
                        },
                        (r, l) -> {
                            log.info("combiner r:{}, l:{}", r, l);
                            r.addAll(l);
                            return r;
                        });
System.out.println(list);
```

The first result：

```
20:52:35.709 [main] - accumulator r:[], l:[b1, b2]
20:52:35.709 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] - accumulator r:[], l:[a1, a2]
20:52:35.711 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] - combiner r:[b1, b2], l:[b1, b2]
[b1, b2, b1, b2]
```

The second result：

```
20:53:09.781 [main] - accumulator r:[], l:[b1, b2]
20:53:09.782 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] - accumulator r:[], l:[a1, a2]
20:53:09.783 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] - combiner r:[b1, b2, a1, a2], l:[b1, b2, a1, a2]
[b1, b2, a1, a2, b1, b2, a1, a2]
```

The third result：

```
20:53:27.321 [main] - accumulator r:[], l:[b1, b2]
20:53:27.321 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] - accumulator r:[], l:[a1, a2]
20:53:27.324 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] - combiner r:[a1, a2], l:[a1, a2]
[a1, a2, a1, a2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using parallel streams, you should never modify accumulator value inside the reduce function, return a new instance instead. In your code, two threads modify the same instance of the accumulator concurrently, so indeed, the result is non-deterministic.

To see what's happening add logging after `r.addAll(l)`:

```java
(r, l) -> {
    log.info("accumulator before r:{}, l:{}", r, l);
    r.addAll(l);
    log.info("accumulator after r:{}", r);
    return r;
}
```

Here are the logs:

```
accumulator before r:[], l:[b1, b2]
accumulator before r:[], l:[a1, a2]
accumulator after r:[b1, b2]
accumulator after r:[b1, b2, a1, a2]
combiner r:[b1, b2, a1, a2], l:[b1, b2, a1, a2]
```

- thread 1 enters reduce function, accumulator is []
- thread 2 enters reduce function, accumulator is []
- thread 1 adds [b1,b2] to the accumulator so it becomes [b1,b2]
- thread 2 adds [a1,a2] to the accumulator so it becomes [b1,b2,a1,a2]
- combiner combines the same instance of the accumulator twice: [b1, b2, a1, a2, b1, b2, a1, a2]

Correct implementation would be as follows:

```java
List<String> list = Stream.of("a", "b").parallel().map(e -> List.of(e + "1", e + "2"))
        .reduce(new ArrayList<>(),
                (r, l) -> {
                    log.info("accumulator before r:{}, l:{}", r, l);
                    var res = new ArrayList<>(r);
                    res.addAll(l);
                    return res;
                },
                (r, l) -> {
                    log.info("combiner r:{}, l:{}", r, l);
                    var res = new ArrayList<>(r);
                    res.addAll(l);
                    return res;
                });
```